# Discord.py: Using Variable As Discord Embed color

Tags: python, discord, embed, discord.py

so I'm trying to make a command for my discord bot that is an embed builder. I want the user of the command to be able to input a hex value for the color of the embed. Here is what I've tried:

```py
value = message.content

embed=discord.Embed(title='Hey', description="How are you?", color=value)
await output.edit(content=None, embed=embed)
```

However when I do this I get the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty but received str instead.
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I think that this is an amazing question to be asked! I had a very similar issue when I was beginning to write Discord bots, and I spent hours scouring documentation trying to find an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that the input you are expecting is something along the lines of `#ffffff`, and please do correct me if I am mistaken. In order to convert this into something that Discord can read, we can use the following method. I'm going to me assuming that `message` is the message object that you wait for them to respond with.

```
sixteenIntegerHex = int(message.content.replace("#", ""), 16)
readableHex = int(hex(sixteenIntegerHex), 0)

embed = discord.Embed(
    title = "Hey",
    description = "How are you?",
    color = readableHex
)
```

You could even merge the two integer conversion statements into one!

```
readableHex = int(hex(int(message.content.replace("#", ""), 16)), 0)
```

Comment: Okay, so, I tried implementing this, but I get the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() can't convert non-string with explicit base`

Comment: I made a simple error in my code, and I am so sorry! Everything should now be working properly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the user input in `message.content` to a RGB color value.

E.g. for green, what `Embed` expects would look like this:

```
discord.Embed(title="Hey", description="How are you?", color=0x00ff00)
```

So you could either let the users pass the color values directly:

```
color = int(message.content, 16)  # content should look like this: "0x00ff00"
discord.Embed(title="Hey", description="How are you?", color=color)
```

Or map some color names to the corresponding values:

```
color_name = message.content  # content should look like this: "green"

colors = {"green": 0x00ff00, "red": 0xff0000, "blue": 0x0000ff}

discord.Embed(title="Hey", description="How are you?", color=colors[color_name])
```

Comment: Ahh, I understand. This worked, thank you (:

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
questions = ["What should be the name of the embed?", 
            "What should be the desc",
            "What is the colour of the embed?"]

answers = []

def check(m):
    return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel 

for i in questions:
    await ctx.send(i)

    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send('You didn\'t answer in time, please be quicker next time!')
        return
    else:
        answers.append(msg.content)


title = answers[1]
desc = answers[2]
colour = answers[3]


embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{title}", description = f"{desc}", color = colour)

embed.set_footer(text = f"My embed")

await channel.send(embed = embed)
```

Comment: I'll try this out, may be a bit difficult to implement it the way I'm trying but hey, worth a shot! Thanks for your contribution (:

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx, content, colour):

embed=discord.Embed(title='Embed', description=f"{content}", color=colour)
await output.edit(content=None, embed=embed)
```

Does this work in your situation?

Comment: At least an example

Comment: No, in my situation I'm accepting different responses for different parts the embed until the bot gets to color. Here you can see where I'm waiting for the input: `message = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
embed=discord.Embed(title='Hey', description="How are you?", color=hex(value))
```

Comment: we appreciate your answer but please provide a bit explnation as well to your answer -- FROM REVIEW